Test that an item has appeared with different time interval - Cypress
i wanted to ask if there is a way i can test if an item has appeared in the app.
For example it can be that i clicked on a button but after 30 mins or 1hr or 1 min, i get a notification that my item has appeared.
The time interval in which the item can appear vary.
I do not want to use timeout or wait as they won't be fixed values.
Is there a way to do this with cypress please?
Thank you

You have the wrong idea about timeout, it's not a fixed wait it's a maximum wait.
cy.get(element, {timeout: 3600_000})   // maximum 1 hour timeout

If the element you are seeking appears in 1 minute the test will continue after 1 minute, it will not wait for the whole hour.
